# Visual Basics 400 error in Excel macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a

> 400 error

when clicking on my macro, when I am in Visual Basic and step thru using <kbd>F8</kbd> it works fine but when ever I click on the Calculate Stats macro it gives a

> 400 error

and won't run it unless I manually put a date in one of the rows. I want it to run without putting the date in and it automatically calculate the date. Sorry, I am new to programming and don't know what more I can say for this to make sense. Please see the code below:

```
Sub CalculateStats_Click()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    'start row specified below as i
    i = 12
    'stop row specified as x
    x = 94

    Dim startloc As String
    Dim stoploc As String
    Dim reportcol As Integer


    Range("A11").End(xlToLeft).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell = Date
    reportcol = ActiveCell.Column

    Do While i < x
        startloc = "H" & i
        stoploc = "I" & i
        Cells(i, reportcol).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Analysts").Range(Worksheets("Analysts").Range(startloc), Worksheets("Analysts").Range(stoploc)))
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A11").End(xlToLeft)` are you sure you want to go left from ColA?  Which lines gives the error, and what is the name of the sheet with the button which calls your code?

Comment: Well it was right but it worked better when I did the F8 in the compiler. the error was coming from ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select but I changed it from -1 to 1 and worked better in the compiler. Analyst is the name.

Comment: Why would you make a range selection `Range("A11").End(xlToLeft).Select`, do nothing with it, then make another selection `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select`  ?, or so it appears to me.

Comment: Also, an `Option Explicit` at the very beginning would help narrow down the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked this out. Thanks for your help with this but it was due to the fact that the Macro was unassigned to the correct Module.

How can I close this ticket?

Answer (score 1):

This is my best guess at what you're trying to do:

```
Sub CalculateStats_Click()

    Const RW_START As Long = 12
    Const RW_END As Long = 93
    Const COL_SUM_START As Long = 8 'H

    Dim i As Long, sht As Worksheet, c As Range

    Set sht = Worksheets("Analysts")

    'find the first empty header cell and populate the date
    Set c = sht.Cells(RW_START - 1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
    c.Value = Date

    For i = RW_START To RW_END
        sht.Cells(i, c.Column).Value = _
            Application.Sum(sht.Cells(i, COL_SUM_START).Resize(1, 2))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, still getting the 400 error when trying to run the macro. Though it does work if putting in the date first. That is something I'm tyring to avoid.

Comment: **Where is the error** ?  Which line is highlighted when it stops?